# Identifying which Horus heresy book this happens in?

Tags: episode-identification, warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

I am going back to the start of the *Horus Heresy* books. It has been a long time since I read them.

I thought the first book covered the events at Ullnor, the moment the Emperor announced he was returning to Terra and was going to name one of his sons war master. I remember a scene where Malcador tells Horus ahead of time he will be chosen.

However having got into book 1 it is clear this picks up a year after this happened and I don't seem to have come across this scene yet.

Which of the early *Horus Heresy* books covers these events first in detail? (I know various books and stories cover the same events from different perspectives throughout the series).

Comment: I cannot tell you which one did, but I can tell you the first six books don't, at least not in details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I remember a scene where Malcador tells Horus ahead of time he will be chosen.

This scene appears in *Slaves to Darkness*. In this novel, Horus

> is left physically wounded his fight with Leman Russ in *Wolfsbane* and his mind is broken.

Horus has a flashback of a scene in Ullanor where

> Horus wanders alone the night before the big celebration and his nomination as War Master. He is then joined by Malcador and they discuss the implications of Horus' new title.